# Why does my program run faster when I overload the system with other arbitrary work?

Tags: c, linux, performance, optimization

I was running some timing and efficiency tests and came across some unexpected behavior. I found that my program actually ran faster if I ran other background processes that pegged all of the systems CPU cores at 100%. Here is a simplified example program:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void vadd(const float *u, const float *v, float *y, int n) {
    int  i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        y[i] = u[i] + v[i];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, its = 100000, n = 16384;
    float *a, *b, *c;
    clock_t start, end;
    double cpu_time;

    /* Make sure alignment is the same on each run. */
    posix_memalign((void**)&a, 16, sizeof(float) * n);
    posix_memalign((void**)&b, 16, sizeof(float) * n);
    posix_memalign((void**)&c, 16, sizeof(float) * n);

    /* Some arbitrary initialization */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
        b[i] = 4;
        c[i] = 0;
    }

    /* Now the real work */
    start = clock();
    for (i = 0; i < its; i++) {
        vadd(a, b, c, n);
    }
    end = clock();

    cpu_time = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Done, cpu time: %f\n", cpu_time);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm running on a (rather old) Pentium 4 @ 2.8GHz with Hyper Threading turned on which shows up as two processors in /proc/cpuinfo.

Output with the system relatively idle:

```
$ ./test
Done, cpu time: 11.450000
```

And now loading all cores:

```
$ md5sum /dev/zero& ./test; killall md5sum
Done, cpu time: 8.930000
```

This result is consistent. I'm guessing that I've somehow improved cache efficiency by reducing the number of time the program gets moved to the other CPU, but this is just a shot in the dark. Can anyone confirm or refute this?

Secondary question: I was surprised to find that cpu_time could vary so much from run to run. The method used above is [taken right out of the GNU C manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/CPU-Time.html#CPU-Time), and I thought that using `clock()` would protect me from timing fluctuations due to other processes using the CPU. Clearly based on the above results this isn't the case. So my secondary question is, is the `clock()` method really the proper way to measure performance?

**Update:** I've looked into the suggestions in the comments about CPU frequency scaling governor, and I don't think that's what is going on here. I've attempted to monitor the CPU speed in real time via `watch grep \"cpu MHz\" /proc/cpuinfo` (as suggested [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_Frequency_Scaling)) and I don't see a frequency change while the programs are running. I should have also included in my post that I'm running a fairly old kernel: 2.6.25.

**Update 2:** I started using the script below to play around with the number of md5sum processes that are started. Even when I start more processes than logical CPU's it's faster than running stand alone.

**Update 3:** If I turn off Hyper Threading in the BIOS this strange behavior goes away and the run always takes around 11 seconds of CPU time. Looks like Hyper Threading has something to do with it.

**Update 4:** I just ran this on a dual quad core Intel Xeon @ 2.5GHz and didn't see any of the above strange behavior. This "issue" may be fairly specific to my particular hardware setup.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i num=$1

for (( num; num; num-- )); do
  md5sum /dev/zero &
done

time ./test
killall md5sum
```

--

```
$ ./run_test.sh 5
Done, cpu time: 9.070000

real    0m27.738s
user    0m9.021s
sys 0m0.052s

$ ./run_test.sh 2
Done, cpu time: 9.240000

real    0m15.297s
user    0m9.169s
sys 0m0.080s

$ ./run_test.sh 0
Done, cpu time: 11.040000

real    0m11.041s
user    0m11.041s
sys 0m0.004s
```

Comment: looks like a typical observation when the CPU in on-demand frequency scaling governor...

Comment: Switch all CPUs to performance mode and try again. You do that with `cpufreq-set -r -g performance` (as root.) If the command isn't available, install the "cpufrequtils" package of your distro.

Comment: @NikosC.Thanks I'll try that. I'm on an embarrassingly old linux distro that no longer has package management support so I'll need to build cpufrequtils from source first. I do have a program called cpufreq-selector that takes the options --cpu, --governer, and --frequency, but no man page for it...

Comment: You can also run the test a couple of times in quick succession, drop the outliers and average over the rest...

Comment: @NikosC.Attempting to set the governor to "performance" yields: "No cpufreq support". So this might be a dead end. But your and TheCodeArtists explanations do seem reasonable.

Comment: Don't trust the numbers you get from `cpufreq`. I doubt it measures it correctly since it's probably just a lame wrapper over `rdtsc`. You need to use something like CPUz.

Comment: As a linux alternative to CPUz I just used dmidecode. Not sure if that's any better, but it reports current speed at 2800MHz, max speed 3200MHz. Current speed reported by dmidecode doesn't change over the course of a test run. Also, I just turned off Hyper Threading in the BIOS and re-ran my tests. I don't see this behavior with Hyper Threading off, so looks like it has something to do with Hyper Threading.

Comment: Re: "No cpufreq support". You may have to load the module first; try `modprobe acpi-cpufreq` and then re-run the command. Or `find /lib/modules -name \*cpufreq\*` to get ideas of what module to try :-)

Answer (score 1):

> So my secondary question is, is the clock() method really the proper way to measure performance?

You could prefer using [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) and friends. Read also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)

Details could be hardware (i.e CPU + motherboard) and kernel specific.

Answer (score 0):

With a single process running on a core, `clock()` should return how much time that process spent running. This includes time that the core was actually executing and time that the core was waiting for things like fetching instructions and data from cache/memory, waiting for the results of one instruction that's needed by another instruction, etc. Basically, for this case, `clock()` returns "time spent executing plus lots of tiny little gaps".

For hyper-threading, the same core is shared by 2 "logical CPUs". The core uses all those tiny little gaps in one process to execute the other process, and the core does more total work in less time (due to less time wasted waiting). In this case what should the `clock()` function measure?

For example, if 2 processes both run on the same core for 10 seconds, should `clock()` say that both processes used 10 seconds each, or should `clock()` say that both processes used half of 10 seconds each?

My theory is that on your system `clock()` returns "core time consumed / processes consuming core's time". With one process running for 10 seconds `clock()` returns "10 seconds", and with 2 of these processes sharing the core they might run for 16 seconds instead of 20 seconds (due to the core wasting less time on "gaps") and `clock()` returns "16/2 = 8 seconds for each process"; making it seem like the process ran 2 seconds faster when there was more load (even though it took 16 seconds instead of 10 seconds).

Comment: I don't think your theory is valid: `clock()` uses `clock_gettime`

Comment: I agree. I just looked into this and played with the number of md5sum processes I start with my program. Adding more md5sums increases the realtime duration of the processing, but CPU time is unaffected. (Until I run the program without any md5sums and it actually takes longer.)